# User not displayed in search

Tags: bug, user-accounts, search, users

When I search for Robert Bryant under users I only see users 84371. Yet account 10727 seems to belong to him also, but this is not displayed in the search results. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I only see 10727 when I search in meta, but when I search on main, I only see 84371. I had thought that only registered accounts showed up in the search, but the unregistered account 10727 shows up (in meta).

I see that there is no meta account for 84371. Perhaps he has not opened meta with that account.

Comment: I only searched in main, but the behaviour you describe seems even stranger.

Comment: @Michael: The meta search shows the only account he has there. I don't see anything stranger about that.

Comment: But why would it not show that same account on main?